# Block access in robot.txt

Tags: robots.txt

If I want to block access to all .py files in my server but allow all files in the same folder as this .py files, what should I put in my robot.txt? This is what I have right, now:

```
User-Agent: *    
Disallow: /*_.py
```

Comment: Why `*_.py?` Wouldn't you want `*.py`?

Comment: The file has to be named `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/search-engine/robots-txt.asp) and [this one](http://ghita.org/search-engines-dynamic-content-issues.html), specific crawlers/robots (e.g. Googlebot and MSNBot) do support the use of the asterisk (*) in the "Disallow:" line.

For example, if you want to block Googlebot from your .py files, you'd use:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.py$
```

The dollar sign ($) designates the end of the filename (including its extension). Note that Googlebot-Image and MSNBot also follow this syntax. However, since I wasn't able to find information about support for this feature for other crawlers, you might want to specify the syntax for the "User-agent"s mentioned in this post.

Of course, it'd be better in the long run to find a universal solution, but this might be a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "defined standard" for `robots.txt` files, but there is a lot of information aggregated on http://www.robotstxt.org/.

On http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html, it is stated:

> Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".

Although some crawlers *do* allow wildcards, if you want to have a reliable solution your safest bet would be to assume that *no* crawler would take your `Disallow:` line into account, and suggest that you find an alternative solution. Otherwise, you will have implemented a solution that will have support from some search engines, whilst leaving your site wide open to others.